# Run npm commands from cmake project

Tags: node.js, npm, cmake

I've got complex C++ project. Now I added c++ node.js addon to my CMake-based project. I want build this adddon with entire project, so I need to modify cmake file in respectively.
Inside of my root cmake file I did following:

```
add_subdirectory(nodejsaddon)
add_custom_target (
npm-target
COMMAND cd nodejsaddon && npm install node-addon-api && npm run build
)
```

`nodejsaddon` - the name of folder with my addon sources and corresponding .gyp and .json files. However, when I run `cmake ..\\testproj\\ -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" -T "v140, host=x64`
I dont see npb build result in nodejsaddon folder.
What I'm doing wrong? How to make npm generate build files in nodejsaddon folder?

Answer (score 4):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html

First, Custom Targets do not run during project generation.  They run during the build process, e.g, `cmake --build .` to build the project.

Secondly, The Custom Target usually only runs when explicitly building that target.  e.g. `cmake --build . --target npm-target`

If you want `npm-target` to be part of the `ALL` target then add `ALL` to the command:

`add_custom_target (npm-target ALL COMMAND cd nodejsaddon && npm install node-addon-api && npm run build )`

If the target is dependent on other targets being built first then use `add_dependencies()` to add dependency information.

But it's not clear if you really expect this to be run during every build or just once during project generation.

Comment: Thanks, will try your suggestions. I need install node-addon-api and run build command only during project generation. `npm run build` generates project files for the addon, so I don't need to generate them by cmake (just need run build from cmake), but I need add generated project file to the whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your command during configure, use `execute_process`.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html

If you want to execute your command during build, you might consider using `add_custom_command`. This does not create a new build targe.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html